# Adding Firebase RecyclerView on a Fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm trying to build an application for my School where in I have made a tab layout and trying to trigger news and information on a fragment through recyclerview, I'm stuck at making it work on a fragment. How do it do it? Thanks

Below is the code of my Activities.

Model Class

```
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;

/**
 * Created by ayushmaniac on 12/10/17.
 */

public class Model {
    String title, image;

    public Model (String image, String title){

        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Model(){

    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }

    public String getImage(){
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image){
        this.image=image;
    }
}
```

Fragment where i want to post news in image and texts

```
   package com.tabs.ayushmaniac.letsmanageit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    public TwoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef=database.getReference("Data");

        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ModelViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = 
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ModelViewHolder>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ModelViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                        Model.class,
                        R.layout.design_row;
                        ModelViewHolder.class,
                        myRef)
                        {

                            @Override
                            protected void populateViewHolder (ModelViewHolder viewHolder, Model
                            model,int position){

                            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                            viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());
                        }
                        }; 
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
                    }
                }
                public static class ModelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                    View mView;

                    public ModelViewHolder(View itemView){
                        super(itemView);
                        mView=itemView;
                    }

                }


    }




}
```

Comment: In your questions code there is not even a try to implement it, so you basically want us to create it for you? You may be better off displaying the exact issue you are experiencing, there is much information on how to perform this action on the web.

Comment: New here sir, posted my old code, studio gives too much of error here, if you can help me